# How to install ownCloud in Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, owncloud-server

I'm having problem installin ownCloud.

I'm following the instructions you can find here: http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:community&package=owncloud

But it says that the "php5-gd, php-xml-parser, php5-mcrypt and ntp" is needed for it to work but can't be installed.

I'm runnin 12.04 Server for anyone that wonders

What should I do?

Comment: How are you installing it? What is the exact error you are getting? Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/527120/edit) your question and include those details.

Answer (score 0):

You're on **Installing Prerequisites For ownCloud** according to this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-owncloud-5-on-ubuntu-12-10). try updating or enabling your software sources in Software and Updates. (main, universe, resrticted, multiverse) also Canonical Partners in the PPA list and Independent.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Here's the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/527123/edit) link...

Comment: Is it better @Parto